# Python: Having issues displaying values from a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm having issues displaying the keys from within a dictionary based on user input. Whenever I run the code without the `hour -=1`, it only displays `'doce'` when I'm trying to display whatever number the user inputs. If I allow the `hour -= 1` in, it displays `'once'`. I've even tried turning the input into an integer but I still get the same issues. Thank you for help in advance.

```
conversion = {1: 'uno', 2: 'dos', 3:'tres', 4:'cuatro', 5: 'cinco', 6: 'seis', 7:'siete', 8:'ocho', 9:'nueve', 10: 'dies', 11: 'once', 12:'doce' }
for hour in conversion:
    hour -= 1
    new_hour = conversion.get(hour)
print (new_hour)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't get any user input.

Comment: you should `print (new_hour)` for each iteration. Actually you're only printing the last value of the loop. and remember: dictionaries are not sorted.

Comment: I did not show the input part of the code because I mentioned it in the paragraph plus it is a simple 'hour = raw_input('enter hour: ')

Comment: Are you trying to convert a single hour into its text equivalent in the dictionary?  If the user types "1", you want to display "uno"?  That's not what your description says you're trying to do, nor what your code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the whole dictionary then write the print statement inside the for loop will do.

If you want to display value based on user input key:

```
key = int(input("please enter a key: "))
value = conversion[key]
print(value)
```

It would be more helpful to show us the full code and explains exactly what would like to do here.

Comment: ahh yes, I see I was just iterating through the dictionary instead of simply isolating a single value. I have it figured out now